# I want to convert my data read from a wave file into a byte array using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import wave as wv 
import numpy as np 
import struct 
wavefile=wv.open("/home/rahul/python/sample.wav",'rb')(nchannels,samplewidth,framerate,nframes,comptype,compname)=wavefile.getparams()
wavedata=wavefile.readframes(2) 
print "channels:",nchannels
print "sample width:",samplewidth
print "framerate:",framerate
print "no of frames:",nframes 
print "comptype:",comptype
print "compname:",compname 
wavefile.close()
```

the Output is::

```
channels:1
samplewidth:2
framerate:44100
no of frames:220500
comptype:NONE
compname:not compressed
```

This is necessary to be into byte array because i have to read them 3 bytes at a time,split them into 4 parts of 6 bits each and them assign them characters according to a reference table so as to convert into text file and then compress this text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can get `wav` file into `Byte` `array`.

```
import array
byte_array = array.array('B')
audio_file = open("buh.wav", 'rb')
byte_array.fromstring(audio_file.read())
print len(byte_array)
audio_file.close()
```

The file size was 52Kb

```
>>> len(byte_array)
53054
```

Read 3 bytes

```
>>> byte_array[0:3]
array('B', [82, 73, 70])
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.However i have one question,that is, i was using scipy and numpy arrays to create an array storing my data and was able to regenerate my wav file. Now if i were to recreate this wav file using this byte array how would i be able to do that?

Comment: If this answer works then do accept it and then ask another question as the next question was not part of original question.